# Apache Ignite: SQL not working with Protobuf object

Tags: ignite

Below are my key and value object in ignite.
Index key and affinity key is annotated in Key object.
Attached grid gain control center UI. Schema name is `KNOWLEDGETIME`

`VdtProto.KnowledgeTime.class` this is Protobuf object.

```
Key.class, VdtProto.KnowledgeTime.class
```

Inserted few records to cache and trying to query using below sql but not returning any records. Why? I tried with plain java pojo object, it's working.

```
SELECT * FROM "test-client_null_cacheName10"."KNOWLEDGETIME"
```

[image: grid gain UI]